# Length of ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I find the size of an ArrayList in Java? I do not mean the number of elements, but the number of indexes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList hash = new ArrayList(5);
    System.out.println(hash.size());
}
```

Prints out "0." Using:

```
    System.out.println(hash.toArray().length);
```

Also prints out a "0."
I have looked in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html but I do not see a method that will help me. Is my ArrayList reverting to a size of 0 if I do not add anything to it?

EDIT The assignment is to create a hash table using ArrayList. I am supposed to create a hash function using the formula

```
    double hashkey = Math.floor(hash.size()*(Math.E*key-Math.floor(Math.E*key)));
```

Where key is an integer. hashkey then becomes the index where the value will be stored. I am using hash.size() as a placeholder at the moment, but that value should be the capacity of my ArrayList.

Comment: there is a difference between initial capacity and size. capacity defines initial memory allocation to array but don't have any object.

Comment: What is the need for the information? Is it just for the sake of education, or is to solve a specific programming problem? If the latter, then smells of an XY problem.

Comment: The implementation hides the size of the underlying array.  Also, a list is most definitely *not* a hash.

Comment: There's no such method. Why would you need it? Note: You could get it by using reflection in an `ArrayList`, but seems for curiosity purposes only, so there's no good to solve it.

Comment: It's also a bit confusing to call an ArrayList `hash`. That's a recipe for disaster. You may as well call your HashMap `array`.

Comment: You can think of an arraylist as an array that magically resizes itself to fit a (more or less) unlimited number of items. You don't need to worry about whats its doing "under the hood". Telling it roughly how many items it's likely to hold helps it be a little more efficient but beyond that don't worry about it's internal workings

Comment: `I do not mean the number of elements, but the number of indexes`, but number of elements = number of indexes.

Comment: You could call `trimToSize()` on your `ArrayList`; this "[t]rims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size." Then you'll know the capacity is `size()`.

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayList.size()` will give the current size.That's why `hash.size()` giving you the current size of your `ArrayList` hash. It will not give you the capacity.
You just initialized the list. Have not add any elements to your arraylist, that's why its giving 0.

Comment: `ensureCapacity()` increases the capacity to _at least_ the number passed to it; it could theoretically make it more than that. I don't think a maxmimum is specified.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard You are right. I added the same because we can use the ensureCapacity() method to check that the internal data structure has enough capacity before adding elements.Although I removed the same.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method in the `ArrayList` API.  The capacity of an `ArrayList` is hidden by design.

However, I think that your question is based on a misunderstanding.

> How do I find the size of an ArrayList in Java? I do not mean the number of elements, but the number of indexes.

In fact, the size of a `List`, the number of elements in a `List`, and the number of indexes (i.e. indexable positions) for a `List` ... are all the same thing.

The capacity of an `ArrayList` is something different.  It is the number of elements that the object *could* contain, without reallocating the list's backing array.  However, the fact that the list has a capacity `N` does NOT mean that you can index up to `N - 1`.  In fact, you can only index up to `size() - 1`, irrespective of the capacity.

---

Now to deal with your examples:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(5);
System.out.println(list.size());
```

This prints out zero because the list has zero elements.  The `ArrayList()` and `ArrayList(int)` constructors both create and return lists that are empty.  The list currently has space for 5 elements (because you gave it an initial capacity of 5) but you can't index those slots.

```
System.out.println(list.toArray().length);
```

This prints zero because when you copy the list's contents to an array (using `toArray()`), the array is the same size as the list.  By definition.

This does not mean that the list's backing array has changed.  On the contrary, it is still big enough to hold 5 elements without reallocation ... just like before.

But ... I hear you say ... the array's length is zero!

Yes, but that is not the *backing* array!  The `toArray()` method allocates a *new* array and copies the `List` contents into that array.  It does NOT return the actual backing array.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should encapsulate your `ArrayList` in a class and add another attribute `private int capacity` in that class as well.

```
public class AdvancedArrayList<T>
{
  private int capacity;
  private ArrayList<T> list;
  public AdvancedArrayList<T>(int capacity)
  {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    list = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  public ArrayList<T> getList()
  {
    return list;
  }
  public int getCapacity()
  {
    return capacity;
  }
  public void addElement(T element)
  {
     if(list.size() < capacity)
        list.add(element);
     else
        System.out.println("Capacity is full");
  }
}
```

Notice that **size** is different than **capacity**.

Comment: If we're going to limit the size like this, we may as well just use an ordinary array.  The whole point of an `ArrayList` is the automatic growth.

Comment: You are right. But OP might want to use `add()` method or change the capacity later on, maybe.

Comment: Yes, but it would be quite difficult to mirror the capacity of the underlying `ArrayList` - you'd have to basically copy the algorithm for choosing when to resize, and how much to resize by.  If you don't do that, you've just got a field that's potentially different from the `ArrayList`'s true capacity, and that's probably not what the OP had in mind.